# Error in clicking event presenting the current TIme in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, time, textbox

Alright so I have wanted to take the current time and then put it in a `TextBox` I made in Windows Form AFTER clicking a button. SO far I have got this much. But I have gotten many problems and I have given up so I came here for help. Btw is this even possible?

**Errors**:

> 1) No overload for 'OnTimedEvent' matches delegate
>   'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'
>
> 2) Member 'Time.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' cannot
>   be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name
>   instead

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Time {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, TextBox textBox1) {
            textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        }
        public static void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have wanted to take the current time and then put it in a text box"  There's no reason to use `System.Timers.Timer` here, use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead as it will run in the main UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the `OnTimedEvent()` method's signature, which won't work.

Remove that last parameter, and remove the `static` keyword from all 3 places you currently have it.

Then the following event method should work:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
}
```

Comment: Additional: You don't see it in this file but `textBox1` is already a private member of this class. That means you don't have to pass it in any methods that you create within this class. There should be a Form1.designer.cs file. That's where all the stuff you drop onto the form via the WYSIWYG designer.

Comment: Ah yes. Good catch. I missed the static keyword in there. @Incin - you probably don't need or want a static variable there.